# How to expose /actuator/startup endpoint?

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator, health-check

I'm trying to expose 3 endpoints:

1. `actuator/health/liveness`
2. `actuator/health/readiness`
3. `actuator/startup`

Adding `management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true`
to my `application.properties` works for 1. and 2. In this case I get info message ""Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'".

Using only `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=startup` doesn't work neither. I get info message ""Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'" though.

How can I expose the 3r endpoint?

I already use `BufferingApplicationStartup` as an `ApplicationStartup` and use both GET and POST to request actuator/startup when testing.

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration should do it:

```
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,startup
```

Assuming your main class is something along the following lines:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ActuatorEndpointApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ActuatorEndpointApplication.class);
            app.setApplicationStartup(new BufferingApplicationStartup(2048));
            app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should, but it doesn't

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using?